# InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 on XPath results

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

Currently I'm trying to run an xPath and then turn each results set into a DOM object so I can search it for a few things, but I keep getting a DOM Exception 11 or Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Code:

```
getDataForOutput = function() {
    log("Getting Loading Necessary Data from XML ["+settings.rowPath+"]");
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var nodes=rawXML.selectNodes(path);

        alert('Currently not IE compatible');

        for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
            //
        }
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var nodes=rawXML.evaluate(settings.rowPath, rawXML, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result=nodes.iterateNext();
        log(nodes);

        while (result) {
            //log("result");
            for(i in settings.columns) {
                if(typeof outputCols[i] == "function") { continue; }
                if(typeof outputCols[i] == "undefined") { outputCols[i] = new Array(); }
                //log($(result).find(settings.columns[i].tag)[0]);

                var data;
                //THE LINE BELOW CAUSES THE DOM EXCEPTION 11 TO HAPPEN....
                var ele = $(result).find(settings.columns[i].tag)[0];
                //THE LINE ABOVE IS EVIL. I EVEN TRIED TO USE:
                //var ele = $(jQuery.extend({}, result)).find(settings.columns[i].tag)[0];
                //BUT IT GIVES OFF: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation 
                if(settings.columns[i].nodeName == true) {
                    data = result.tagName;
                } else if(settings.columns[i].nodeValue == true) {
                    data = result.textContent;
                } else if(typeof settings.columns[i].attr != "undefined") {
                    data = result.getAttribute(settings.columns[i].attr);
                }

                outputCols[i].push(data);
            }

            result = nodes.iterateNext(); //Gives Dom Excepti
        }
    }
    log("Data loaded");
},
```

Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 xmlEditor.js:229
XMLEditor.getDataForOutput xmlEditor.js:229
XMLEditor.outputData xmlEditor.js:70
XMLEditor.loadXML xmlEditor.js:63
XMLEditor.init xmlEditor.js:23
XMLEditor xmlEditor.js:364
(anonymous function) edit_translation.html?page=cerep_assay_translation&sso.token=ffc469425b70b2…en&last_name=Brice&email=steven.m.brice@abbvie.com&external_id=bricesm1:22
l jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
c.fireWith jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
S
```

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
t.nodeType.t.documentElement.i.find.TAG.n.getElementsByTagName.r jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
St jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
ot jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
x.fn.extend.find jquery-2.0.1.min.js:5
XMLEditor.getDataForOutput xmlEditor.js:219
XMLEditor.outputData xmlEditor.js:70
XMLEditor.loadXML xmlEditor.js:63
XMLEditor.init xmlEditor.js:23
XMLEditor xmlEditor.js:366
(anonymous function) edit_translation.html?page=cerep_assay_translation&sso.token=ffc469425b70b2…en:22
l jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
c.fireWith jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery-2.0.1.min.js:4
S
```

Answer (score 0):

End up just doing:

```
var ele = result.getElementsByTagName(settings.columns[i].tag)[0];
```